# Alter table structure to match copy table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables `corporate` and `corporate_copy`. Initially they were same in structure but people started added new columns into `corporate` and forgot do do so for `corporate_copy`.

Somewhere in the application there is less used functionality that copies data from `corporate` to `corporate_copy` and that kept failing without anyone noticing. Now I have to add 28 columns (ofcourse with same type and length and constraints etc....).

I know it can be done in one `ALTER TABLE` statement but I still feel it is lengthy task.

Do we have any luxury that will make copy table same as main table by keeping data and adding default values in newly added columns?

I am asking much but is there anything like that?

Comment: Do you want the same data as well in the copy table?

Comment: Data is different, structure is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Generate a dynamic query which contain all the missing column list and Execute it
--for eg I tried Something

    BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE  @SqlSelect NVARCHAR(MAX),@ColumnDeclaration VARCHAR(2000)

    SELECT DISTINCT ' '+COLUMN_NAME+' '+ DATA_TYPE +' '+ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH ),'')+' 'Missing_Column INTO #T FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
    WHERE a.column_name not in (SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b
    WHERE b.table_name in ('Corporate_Copy'))
    and a.table_name in ('Corporate')



    SELECT @ColumnDeclaration=STUFF((
                                SELECT ', ' + Missing_Column 
                                FROM #T
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')

    SET @SqlSelect=' ALTER TABLE Corporate_Copy  Add'+ @ColumnDeclaration + ');'
    PRINT @SqlSelect


    ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Perfect, just need to add constraints to it which I will do. Thanks :)

Comment: @Imad Welcome Bro

Answer (score 0):

You could use schema compare, found in SQL Server data tools (free) to generate a change script automatically.

But if this is just a copy, you could just run this:

```
DROP TABLE Corporate_Copy;

SELECT *
INTO Corporate_Copy
FROM Corporate;
```

It's not clear whether you really need to preserve the data in the copy. If so, it's not really a copy is it?

Comment: a doubt. can we use 'into' with main tables (objects)?

Comment: I am copying rows based on condiiton not entire table and this statement will fail as both table now has different columns.

Comment: @Coder1991 I don't know what you mean by "main tables (objects)".

Comment: After you run this, both tables have identical structure and data. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid nope. there is existing data and I said, I want specific rows not all data.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid A table which is already having some columns along with data (Corporate_Copy). Sorry haven't noticed the drop statement at the beginning.

Comment: @lmad so you want to keep whatever is in the table but add columns to make it match the existing table? I re-suggest you use schema compare in that case, and edit it to make columns nullable

Answer (score 0):

From SQL-Server 2015, you can use the following query to extract all different columns between 2 tables:

```
select distinct a.* from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
where a.column_name not in (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b
where b.table_name in ('tbl_A'))
and a.table_name in ('tbl_B')
order by a.column_name
```

The output gives you enough information to create a simple script to add the columns which are missing:

[image]

For exmaple:

```
Alter table tbl_A ADD res.Column_Name res.Data_Type ....
```

Comment: I did it using ms excel. But questiion is different. I want to add those columns in copy.

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible using `SELECT INTO`, for example the following SQL statement creates a backup copy of corporate:

```
SELECT * INTO corporate_copy
FROM corporate ;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. generate `CREATE` script in SSMS (right-click on table, then "script table as...")
2. Delete all things that already exists. Usually they are in the begining and it's a simple
3. change `CREATE` to `ALTER ... ADD`